# MemoryCache only add if not exist in .NET Core? (similar to MemoryCache.Add in Framework)

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-6.0

.NET Core has a memory cache class `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory`, you can set a value using the `CacheExtensions` cache.

But I would like to add only if the value does not exist yet. Is it possible to do that with `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory`?

If not, what would be the equivalent method for `MemoryCache.Add( ... )` in .NET 4.8 (it returns false in case of duplicates), using .NET Core 6.0?

Answer (score 1):

Use [GetOrCreate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.cacheextensions.getorcreate?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) instead, or [GetOrCreateAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.cacheextensions.getorcreateasync?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) if the value needs to be generated asynchronously.

.NET Framework's [Add](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Runtime.Caching/System/Caching/MemoryCache.cs,500) does as well, it calls `AddOrGetExisting` and returns `true` if there was no existing value :

```
    public override bool Add(CacheItem item, CacheItemPolicy policy) {
        CacheItem existingEntry = AddOrGetExisting(item, policy);
        return (existingEntry == null || existingEntry.Value == null);
    }
```

`Add` hides what's actually going and is easy to implement yourself if you absolutely have to